# How to fix VSCode syntax highlighting for Postgres `COPY` command

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I have a lot of `.sql` files from a PostgreSQL database.

(Just for completeness, they were generated using [pg_extractor](https://github.com/omniti-labs/pg_extractor) as a way of checking in the skeleton of the database in git. There are hundreds of PL/pgSQL functions that need to be checked in too as part of the application code. Developers work on the functions on their local database servers and then check in their function changes to git.)

In these files, data is represented using the PostgreSQL `COPY` command.

For example, our skeleton database has the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    name_display text NOT NULL,
    order_display integer NOT NULL
);

COPY roles (id, name, name_display, order_display) FROM stdin;
1   MASTER  Master  1
2   ORGANIZATION_ADMIN  Organization Admin  2
3   REGIONAL_ADMIN  Regional Admin  3
4   BRANCH_ADMIN    Branch Admin    5
5   SECURITY_ADMIN  Security Admin  8
6   BRANCH_MANAGER  Branch Manager  6
7   BRANCH_STAFF    Branch Staff    7
8   SECURITY_OPERATOR   Security Operator   9
9   REGIONAL_MANAGER    Regional Manager    4
\.
```

While the example above is simple, there are some that are a lot more complex.

The issue I have is when a table contains data with single or double quote marks. In this case, Visual Studio Code thinks that the marks should be opening a quoted string, and messes up the syntax highlighting of the rest of the file. In the actual case of quoted strings, this is not a problem, but if some text contains a possessive (or contractive) apostrophe it causes the rest of the file (unless there is another apostrophe) to be treated as quoted text.

The problem is that there is no way to escape an apostrophe in the `COPY` input because it is expected to be raw values (other than newlines, nulls, the delimiter (tab, by default), and the escape character (`\`) itself).

Is there a way to get VSCode to ignore quotes inside the `COPY` body (from the semicolon at the end of the `COPY` statement until the `\.` that ends the body)?